# Seaborn line plot - only part of date displaying for repetitive CSV data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to display a seaborn line plot for the data in - [MayCSV.csv](https://gofile.io/d/76yBHm) - as date on x-axis and load on y-axis . The CSV has 500 load data for each of the dates. I have written following code lines :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

emp=pd.read_csv("E:\\22_October\\MayCSV.csv")
emp['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(emp['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))    
fig = sns.lineplot(x = "Date", y = "Load", data = emp, ax=ax)

x_dates = emp['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y').sort_values().unique()
plt.grid(True, alpha=1)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

Which gives me this plot
[image]

The problem as can be seen, it displays dates only upto 9th May. What can be done to display all the dates for a complete graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a formatter. `fig.autofmt_xdate` is helpful here as well (though remove the `fig =` from `fig = sns.lineplot...`).

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))    
sns.lineplot(x = "Date", y = "Load", data = emp, ax=ax)

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%d-%m-%Y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

plt.grid(True, alpha=1)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
```

Output:
[image]